# Status Bar Color Change in Compose Multiplatform

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-multiplatform, shared, compose-multiplatform, compose-multiplatform-ios

[image]

I want to change the status bar color. I have tried some code in App.kt file MaterialTheme{
}
But it's not affect on statusbar color.

I want to change the status bar color like the background of then login screen. And make sure it doesn't effect on ios also. I tried edgeToedge(). But it's hiding the status bar. I don't want to hide the status bar. Just wanna change the color in light mode or dark mode.

Answer (score 2):

I have solve the issue by doing this in MainAciviy.kt

```html
enableEdgeToEdge(
            statusBarStyle = SystemBarStyle.light(
                Color.TRANSPARENT, Color.TRANSPARENT
            ),
            navigationBarStyle = SystemBarStyle.light(
                Color.TRANSPARENT, Color.TRANSPARENT
            )
        )
```

This in the ContentView.swift

```html
ComposeView()
                        .ignoresSafeArea(edges: .all)
                        .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
```

Then In CommonMain

```html
Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(Color(0xFFEAFBF2))
                .windowInsetsPadding(WindowInsets.safeDrawing)
        ) {

          }
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not use compose multiplatform so much, but I would add this line to the android Activity

```
        WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
```

This will give you full access of the screen. Then, for bottom navigation on android devices you will probably need to add:

```
        Modifier.windowInsetsPadding(WindowInsets.navigationBars),
```

That you would pass to your main composable.